# Why No Action on GVIM crashes on 17.04 Unity

Tags: unity, vi

I do not understand why there has apparently been no action on the constant crashes in vim-gtk3 in Unity.  The askubuntu entry shows no activity in the last 6 months.  I would actually like to go to 17.10, where this would presumably no longer be an issue, but after an extended period Canonical has not resolved the bios corruption issue which has that release on hold.

Comment: is there are bug on launchpad?, which has a good chance of being seen by bug.squad & thus devs. the more users affected the greater the likelihood of Canonical putting resources in to fix it, beyond just the community (so have you added yourself as an affected user?). If you mean https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/1650666 a workaround was found.  This site is primarily for users, not bugs (or devs)

Comment: Thank you @guiverc.  I applied the workaround from that launchpad entry even before posting.   Another workaround is presumably to switch from Unity to Gnome, which is why if I could install 17.10 on my Dell Laptop this problem would probably go away.  It seems poor marketing to distribute a release which crashes  because of a simple packaging issue unless the client replaces a Gnome3 application with a Gnome2 version especially when dealing with the bad press of the Lenovo catastrophe.